# Enable remote desktop in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, remote-desktop, firewall, netsh

I am trying to enable Remote Desktop in my old Windows 8 laptop.

I did not find a way to do it via GUI, as I do not have the settings shown everywhere ([1](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7e39ca/enable-remote-desktop-connection-in-windows-8/), [2](https://www.guidingtech.com/13469/how-to-enable-remote-desktop-in-windows-8/), etc.)
This is what I have

[image]    [image]

The second image is what I get hitting *Advanced*.

So I looked for a Command Line method ([3](https://www.interfacett.com/blogs/methods-to-enable-and-disable-remote-desktop-locally/), [4](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/enable-remote-desktop-using-command-line), etc.)
What I did:

1. In the registry editor, set `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\fDenyTSConnections` to `0` (it existed, and it was set to `1`).
2. Try at an elevated prompt `netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="remote desktop" new enable=yes`.
   But the command is not available:

   ```
    C:\windows\system32>netsh advfirewall set ?

    The following commands are available:

    Commands in this context:
    set allprofiles - Sets properties in all profiles.
    set currentprofile - Sets properties in the active profile.
    set domainprofile - Sets properties in the domain profile.
    set global     - Sets the global properties.
    set privateprofile - Sets properties in the private profile.
    set publicprofile - Sets properties in the public profile.
   ```

   As per ([5](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/netsh-advfirewall-firewall-control-firewall-behavior#command-example-8-enable-specific-services)), I also tried an older form

   ```
    C:\windows\system32>netsh firewall set service RemoteDesktop enable

    IMPORTANT: "netsh firewall" is deprecated; use "netsh advfirewall firewall" instead.
    For more information on using "netsh advfirewall firewall" commands instead of "netsh firewall", see KB article 947709 at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=121488 .


    C:\windows\system32>netsh advfirewall firewall set service RemoteDesktop enable
    The following command was not found: advfirewall firewall set service RemoteDesktop enable.
   ```

I would like to know why I don't have `set rule` (likely this is an old version of the `netsh` helper), and mostly how to finally allow for remote desktop connections.

Comment: If you cannot get Windows RDP working, see the alternatives: https://alternativeto.net/software/remote-desktop-connection/

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - I am giving a try to dwservice... it looks nice.